# Select the key:value pairs from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python Dict like as follows:

```
a = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"f":4,"d":5}
```

and I have a list like as follows:

```
b= ["b","c"]
```

What I want to do is selecting the key:value pairs from the dict a with keys in b.
So the output should be a dictionary like:

```
out = {"b":2,"c":3}
```

I could simply create another dictionary and update it using the key:value pair with iteration but I have RAM problems and the dictionary a is very large. b includes a few points so I thought popping from a does not work. What can I do to solve this issue?

Edit: Out is actually an update on a. So I will update the a as out.

Thanks :)

Comment: Creating another dictionary no matter how you do it will take memory.  Please state your __real__ problem

Comment: if `b` is very short then there shouldn't be RAM problem, and you can't win from both side, either create new or pop from existing.

Answer (score 14):

If you truly want to create a new dictionary with the keys in your list, then you can use a dict comprehension.

```
a = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"f":4,"d":5}
b = ["b", "c"]

out = {x: a[x] for x in b}
```

This will fail by raising a `KeyError` if any of the elements of `b` are not actually keys in `a`.

Comment: you didn't answer the RAM problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have any problem with modifing the exsisting dict then try this :

```
out = {}
for key in b:
        out[key] = a.pop(key)
```

This **wouldn't take any extra space**, as we're transferring the values required from old to new dict, and would solve the problem of slow selective popping as well(as we're not traversing through all but only the selective one's which are required).

Comment: Since my dictionary a is too large and b is small. I remove most of the keys. Therefore this takes a little more time. Therefore I preferred @Chris Mueller 's solution. Thanks :)

Comment: @uhuuyouneverknow we both are looping on `b` so the time complexity is same.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this,

```
a = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"f":4,"d":5}
b= ["b","c"]

out = {item:a.get(item)for item in b}
```

This won't raise any error, but adds `''` if the item is not in a.

Answer (score -1):

a = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"f":4,"d":5}
b= ["b","c"]

dict1 = {}
for key,value in a.items():
for i in b:
if i == key:
dict1[i] = value
dict1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).